# Storing multiple list values in multiple variable within the for loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have three list and basically i want handle of storing their values in one go within the for loop. Below is what i am trying to accomplish

```
a = ['abc', 'efg']
b = ['hij', 'klm']
c = ['nop', 'qrs']

for i, g, t in a, b, c:
    Insert into database %i and %j and %c
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `zip` built-in function:

```
for i, g, t in zip(a, b, c):
    Insert into database %i and %g and %t
```

> zip([iterable, ...])
>
> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains
>   the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables

You can read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) for more information

**Note:**
If your lists are not equally (by length) you can use the `izip_longest` from itertools lib.

> itertools.izip_longest(*iterables[, fillvalue]) Make an iterator that
>
> aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are
>   of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue.
>   Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.

For more info about izip_longest, read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

Comment: Nitpick: `zip` is a built-in function, not a keyword.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: Thank you @omri_saadon. I am now able to insert multiple values in the database. I thought zip can only be used to zip two list and transform them into dictionary. Never thought zip can work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which is perhaps less clean compared to the `zip` answer provided elsewhere is to:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
for i in range(len(a)):
    insert_into_database(a[i],b[i])
```

would also work but is less clean/elegant :)